# CakePHP 3 routes when using separate Controller namespaces

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.x

This question concerns routing (`config/routes.php`) in CakePHP 3.7.3

I have an application which uses 3 Controllers. Two of these are within an 'Admin' namespace:

- `Controller/Admin/ArticlesController.php`
- `Controller/Admin/UsersController.php`
- `Controller/ArticlesController.php`

I'm trying to achieve the following things:

1. Make a "shortcut" URL `https://example.com/admin` that serves `Admin/UsersController::login()` - i.e. `https://example.com/admin/users/login`
2. The function that shows pages on the frontend of my website is `ArticlesController::view()`. If I have a URL slug "foo" my page serves the content from the URL `https://example.com/articles/view/foo`. However I want to make this just `https://example.com/foo`.

In my `config/routes.php` I have configured Admin routing with this:

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
        // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    });

    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);

});
```

This works - I can login at `https://example.com/admin/users/login`.

To solve (1) I attempted to add the following:

```
Router::connect('/admin', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);

// The line above is immediately outside the existing code shown previously:
Router::scope('/' ...
```

But this gives me an error:

> Error: AdminController could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class AdminController below in file: `src/Controller/AdminController.php`

The Controller it's being asked to use is `Users` so I don't understand why it's asking for an `AdminController`?

To solve (2) I attempted:

```
$routes->connect('/*', ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view]);
```

However when attempting to access `https://example.com/foo` it is giving the following error:

> Error: FooController could not be found.

Clearly this isn't what I'm trying to do - I'm expecting it to use the `Articles` Controller and `view` action I've specified in the array.

In my two Admin Controllers (`Controller/Admin/ArticlesController.php` and `Controller/Admin/UsersController.php`) I have declared:

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;
```

outside the class name, e.g. `class ArticlesController extends AppController`

For the non-Admin `ArticlesController` (`Controller/ArticlesController.php`) I have declared:

```
namespace App\Controller;
```

followed by the class name `class ArticlesController extends AppController`

This seems overly complex. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.php add:

```
Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);
```

For Admin routing:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

and for Public routing:

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
})
```

Comment: For the Admin routing it's giving an error saying "Create the class LoginController below in file: src/Controller/LoginController.php". Not sure why as the controller is called 'Users' and in any case that's in the 'Admin' namespace (i.e. it should be `Controller/Admin/UsersController.php`, not `Controller/UsersController.php`)